# How can one simulate and analyze attacks on the Bitcoin network?

Tags: testnet, attack

Are there any other platforms or tools beside TestNet where I can simulate and analyze various attacks like double spending (finney/block withholding attacks etc.)?

Comment: Do you know about regtest mode?

Comment: Yes, i know about regtest . It is somewhat similar to testnet except that it allows faster generation of blocks. What i am looking for is a tool that can help me model various attacks like >50% , selfish mining and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The `regtest` operational mode of `bitcoind` is not as similar to `testnet` as you might think. The `regtest` mode offers you a totally local Bitcoin blockchain which is easily controlled by your local `bitcoind` with low difficulty. According to [this post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/36014/22795), it is furthermore possible to build a network out of multiple local `bitcoind` instances, such that you have a local Bitcoin network of your own.

You can control this network freely, but you can only simulate behavior that `bitcoind` allows you to assume. I am not aware of whether or not this is sufficient for your cases. If not, you could maybe try to fork `bitcoind` and somehow add the behavior you want to achieve...

Comment: Not sure if a regression testing mode (regtest) should be used, see https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin. Rolling out a private Bitcoin network "isolated from the Internet" could be used to provide an environment for stimulating and monitoring attacks.

Comment: So will it be possible to simulate attacks like 51% on regtest mode ?