# running regtest network, bitcoin.conf incorrectly configured?

Tags: regtest

This is what happens after I run this command `bitcoind --regtest --printtoconsole`, my guess is that it's something to do with bitcoin.conf

[image]

My bitcoin.conf file looks like this:

```
server=1
rpcuser=root
rpcpassword=password
rpcconnect=127.0.0.1
rpcport=8332
```

If you need more context, these are my other questions: [trouble with bitcoin cli regtest](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/52857/trouble-with-bitcoin-cli-regtest) and [interacting with bitcoin over docker](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/52832/interacting-with-bitcoin-over-docker?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: but- I get this- `bitcoin-cli -regtest getinfo
error: couldn't connect to server: unknown (code -1)
(make sure server is running and you are connecting to the correct RPC port)`

Comment: Try removing the rpcconnect line. rpcconnect is an option to bitcoin-cli, not bitcoind.

Comment: ah- I removed it but- same error :/

Comment: In fact, you can delete your bitcoin.conf entirely. bitcoind will create its own password if you don't set one (cookie), and bitcoin-cli can find it. All the other options are default. So I suggest just delete bitcoin.conf, restart bitcoind, and then try again.

Comment: when I delete it I get the error `bitcoin-cli -regtest getinfo` >>
`error: Could not locate RPC credentials. No authentication cookie could be found, and no rpcpassword is set in the configuration file (/root/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf)`

Comment: What version of bitcoind is running? It's in the first line of debug.log.

Comment: Bitcoin version v0.14.99.0-c91ca0a

Comment: I think I need to do something like [described here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/28107/bitcoin-is-not-connected-in-regtest-mode), do you think it's right?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is for you. But no, that link doesn't help. bitcoin-cli fails to connect to your bitcoind entirely. That answer is about needing multiple nodes in your network before you can have all functionality.

Comment: I'm trying to run it on this docker image https://hub.docker.com/r/smatthewenglish/oakcoin/tags/ it's just an ubuntu image with the latest version of bitcoin cloned from github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do this...

To use bitcoind and bitcoin-cli, you will need to add a RPC password to your bitcoin.conf file. Both programs will read from the same file if both run on the same system as the same user, so any long random password will work:

```
  rpcpassword=change_this_to_a_long_random_password
```

in the future I'll be sure to [RTFM](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#testing-applications)